# Lucene 5.4.0 API for Sentiment Analysis

Tags: lucene, classification, sentiment-analysis

Is there any examples or sample codes that I could follow or work around with using Lucene 5.4.0 API for text sentiment analysis to get the polarity score? And also possibly using different classification methods provided by their classification api package?

Answer (score 0):

Using a [Naive Bayes classifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier) is probably the best approach.

You may have a look at this blog which [explain how they used Apache Mahout](http://technobium.com/sentiment-analysis-using-mahout-naive-bayes/) to handle this task.

As you mentioned, you may build you own implementation using the new [classification API from Lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_4_0/classification/index.html).

Your answer is in this tutorial with [sample codes using the classification API](http://soleami.com/blog/comparing-document-classification-functions-of-lucene-and-mahout.html).

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into this